# Is there a way to force a derived type to declare a static method with a specific signature?

Tags: c#-6.0

I need a way to force a subclass of one of my classes to declare a specific static method. For example a type safe FromFile or FromStream function. Similar to the concept of abstract methods for a non static context.

I know I could use constructs like this:

```cs
return (T)typeof(T).GetMethod("FromFile").Invoke(null, new[] { someArgs });
```

But this would only throw an exception during runtime if the method is not defined. But what I want is to make the code not compile if it isn't there.

I also know that I could get all those loader methods at startup and store them in a static Type-Loader map, but still it would only throw an exception during application startup.

For this example I am using a texture loader that should be able to load different types of textures as long as they inherit the same base class.
(OpenGL Texture Wrappers, DX Texture Wrappers, Video Textures, etc)

```cs
public abstract class DataContainer<T>
{
    public abstract T Load(object someArgs);

    [...]
}

public class TextureContainer<T> : DataContainer<T> where T : Texture<T>
{
    public override T Load(object someArgs)
    {
        if (/*is currently loaded*/)
            return GetLoadedFile(someArgs);
        else
            return T.FromFile(someArgs);
    }

    [...]
}
```

A base class for texture would look something like this:

```cs
public abstract class Texture<T> where T : Texture<T>
{
    //works fine, forces derived class to declare a type safe Clone method
    public abstract T Clone();

    //sadly for static methods I can't do the same
    //so I need another way here
    public static /*abstract*/ T FromFile(object someArgs);
}
```

Then a concrete implementation of texture would look like this:

```cs
public class DirectXTexture : Texture<DirectXTexture>
{
    //works fine
    public override DirectXTexture Clone()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    //another way needed
    public static /*override*/ DirectXTexture FromFile()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Having this setup you could simply get a texture by using the following code with the base DataContainer loading and unloading the texture whenever necessary or performing the loading task in a background thread.

```cs
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new TextureContainer<DirectXTexture>();
        var tex = container.Load("some file");
    }
}
```

Just to clarify: I already have a fully working DataContainer construct that can load resources in main or background threads and monitor instances that reference my resources so I can unload them if nobody needs them anymore. The only thing I need is the functionality of creating a container for an ABSTRACT type with their corresponding load methods so I do not have to create a seperate sub class for DXTextureContainer, GLTextureContainer, VideoTextureContainer etc.

I hope you guys can help me here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit: Just added syntax highlighting to the code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Up to **C# 8.0** there's no way to enforce that.

Starting with Visual Studio 2017 you can write a Roslyn analyzer to flag that (and make it a compilation error, if you want it) and even offer a fix.

Comment: Hm. I don't think I can convice the rest of my team to move away from VS 2015 and as far as I know there is no easy way to use **C# 8.0** in VS 2015. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: And an analyzer still would not allow something like
**T.FromFile(someArgs)** or would it?

Comment: Not from `T`, no. Just on a concrete type.